# To what extent (if any) does the Catholic Church recognize adoption?

Tags: catholicism, canon-law, adoption

Assuming the Church recognizes adoption, if a man or woman were to invite another to live together as a loving relationship as parent and child, but without any secular legal process, would the Church recognize the adoption?

I ask this because some Catholics in history and today have lived/live in a land where there is no secular legal process to recognize an adoption.

If the legal document is required, why does secular law have such an impact on Church teaching? (In some countries adoption is completely illegal.)

By "recognize" I mean if it would be a mortal sin if at some point in time the 2 parties changed their minds on the nature of the relationship and decided to get married, or the parent giving up and cutting all ties with the child. So the adoption being just as permanent and having the same dignity as a biological parenthood.

Comment: What does your last paragraph mean? That the man and women of the first paragraph weren't married? Or that a parent marries an adopted child? Or what?

Comment: @curiousdannii If the parent marries an adopted child.

Comment: If there is no legal process by which the child can be recognized as adopted, what's the basis on which they're considered "adopted"?

Comment: @Matt Gutting I'm thinking of a situation like Esther and Mordecai. Where there is a genuine permanent parental bond but no legal process would take place.

Comment: @Matt Gutting I'm assuming the Jews in ancient would not involve themselves with an adoption contract, as they were associated with paganism because a ["Episcopal" Dignitary](http://www.parstimes.com/law/ancient_persia_laws.html) was needed for the contract, and non registry was an option.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that "not recognizing the adoption" doesn't mean the church ignores the relationship. Plenty of people look after children without adopting them, and the church would not see anything wrong in that. They just wouldn't be the child's parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *…without any secular legal process, would the Church recognize the adoption?*

No.

Canon Law defers to civil authorities for the legal recognition of adoption. For example, adopted children must be legally recognized as such before adoptive parents can baptize them ([Can. 877](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2Z.HTM) §3).

[1983 Code canon 110](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKgZEjvB5cEC&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q&f=false) deals with adoption:

> Children who have been adopted according to the norm of civil law are considered the children of the person or persons who have adopted them.

---

Regarding

> *why does secular law have such an impact on Church teaching?*

see:

> [Can. 22](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3.HTM) Civil laws to which the law of the Church yields are to be observed in canon law with the same effects, insofar as they are not contrary to divine law and unless canon law provides otherwise.

It's possible that in the future the Church might devise a "[mechanism or procedure…to secure the institute of adoption](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKgZEjvB5cEC&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q&f=false)."

For more information on the divine, natural, civil, and ecclesiastical laws aspects of marriage, see [*How Marriage Became One of the Sacraments: The Sacramental Theology of Marriage From Its Medieval Origins to the Council of Trent*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6583) by Philip L. Reynolds, §16.5 "Thomas Aquinas on Marriage in Law" pp. 686-715 (PDF pp. 718-747).

Comment: So what would happen to an orphan in state custody who is near death?  His Catholic foster parents couldn't have him baptized?

Comment: @Nathaniel Infants in immanent danger of death can be privately baptized: [Can. 870](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2X.HTM): "An abandoned infant or a foundling is to be baptized unless after diligent investigation the baptism of the infant is established." ([commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKgZEjvB5cEC&pg=PA1059#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The same applies to adults in danger of death ([Can. 865](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2X.HTM) §2).